# The long press in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a little problem and is that I want to show a menu in a WebView when a link is pressed 2,5 seconds. I have to code to show what I want, but I don't know if the menu is a UITableView, and how to say that all the links in the WebView can use this action. Here's some code:

```
-(IBAction)longpress{
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 2.5;
longPress.delegate = self;
[WebLinks(?) addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[longPress release];
NSString *Link = WebLink.text;
}
```

Please answer this if you can, I'll be grateful!

PS: These code has been developed by a friend and me, so please understand that we are new in Objective-C. If you think that our code could be better, please post it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have delegate protocol  in your header file, in @interface implementation? Something like

```
@interface FirstViewController : <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {}
```

Comment: But please answer the question if you can!